# Alternative to (Flash) SimpleViewer image gallery?

Tags: css, flash, gallery

I am using [SimpleViewer](http://www.simpleviewer.net/simpleviewer/) to show images on a website. It's a nice and elegant tool. But, as it is using Flash not all devices (e.g. iPad?) will/can show the images. Does anybody know about a non-Flash alternative? Maybe totally CSS cased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have now, see: [this comment](http://www.simpleviewer.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=45657#p45657) at the SimpleViewer Forum. It's called Universal Playback.

Comment: Well, not a real alternative, but people not using Flash now CAN see the images, although in a less smoother way

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I found something that looks quite a bit like SimplerViewer called Gallerific. https://github.com/iamvery/galleriffic

If you check out the example 2 you'll see a layout that looks a lot like SimpleView

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, looks nice, I'll have a look at Gallerific

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have checked under every rock and I can't find a good non-flash alternative to SimpleViewer (i'm really curious now to if there's one!). There are rumours about it soon being changed to HTML5 (a wise decision), but I don't know if you can wait that long.

I would say the best option is jQuery and CSS, you can personalise and style your gallery as you wish, but you will have to be at least a bit comfortable with html editing. It's not complicated at all, you should give it a try.

You can find lots of jQuery galleries and sliders tutorials here for example: http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/ 
Do some search engine research to get the best options, there are tons of different galleries.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, great answer! Nice link. I will dive into jQuery examples and turorials.